# How to fix 'The system could not find the specified path'?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity, so maybe my problem is really stupid. However, I've been searching through StackOverFlow and no one seems to have the same problems that I am having.

Every time that I try to create a new project in Unity (the template doesn't matter, it happens with all of them) many compilation errors appear (they are all the same one repeated many times).

The error is:

> El sistema no pudo encontrar la ruta especificada

which translates to something like:

> The system could not find the specified path

I don't really understand them because the message errors don't really have any useful information when I click them. When clicked, they say the same thing as before `The system could not find the specified path`.

I've tried things like refreshing the packages, deleting cache stored info and many others, but none worked.

Here's a link to an image showing my errors.
https://gyazo.com/ea6b62f2bbf48665ca0322e07622b7f8

The editor that I am using is the 2021.3.3f1 version, in Windows 10 Home.

Somebody help please I've been smashing my head against the keyboard for a week.

Comment: Hey that's quite a strange error. Might it be possible that the location of your project contains any non alphanumeric characters that might be causing issues?

Comment: Also maybe check if the path to your unity install has a any non alphanumeric characters. Maybe it's trying to load something in that it can't find because of certain characters.

Comment: @Lieke I don't think that's the case, as the project folder's path is simply `D:\projects\myProject` and the installation path is  `D:\UnityEditor\2021.3.3f1`

Comment: Hmm not really sure then. Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing a different version?

Comment: You could also try to open unity with administrator privileges and see if that helps.

Comment: Double-clicking the error will sometimes take you to the offending code.  There at least you may be able to discover if it's a 3rd party package that you could remove.

Comment: @Lieke I've tried both things already and nothing.

Comment: @MickyD Not in my case, when I double click nothing appears.

Comment: It's at least an internal unity bug (as it doesn't have a stacktrace) so you could make a bug report https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/bug-reporting but that might not be very helpful. You could try one last thing and that is to create a different user(windows) account (as you're paths imply windows). And check if that would work. Maybe something else is locking the files? But that is a last ditch effort. Also check if you have the latest os and driver updates as well as restart your computer. And you could of course also make a unity forum post https://forum.unity.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently. I tried a number of things, but the thing I think resolved it was by following this guide: https://superuser.com/questions/727316/error-in-command-line-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified

**From the linked post:**

Try the following.

1. Open the Registry Editor (press +R, type regedit and hit Enter) .
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and clear the values.
3. Also check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`.

Once you do that, restart Unity and try to reopen your project. Errors should no longer appear.

If not, look into the other things I tried:

- downgrading Unity versions in UnityHub
- turning off my firewall + antivirus temporarily

Hope this helps someone out here!